# Low battery warning light

Tags: renault, clio

I drive my car everyday but the low battery warning light came on and I’m unsure of how to charge it without the use of a charger or jump leads.
How long does it typically take for the warning light to go off from simply driving the car?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the warning light is on, it means that the system is not charging for any one of many reasons alternator failure, broken wires, loose connections etc.

You need to check out the battery voltage with and without the engine running or, take it to a person who can.

A long run will not sort the issue you describe.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a low battery warning light. It is lack of charging warning light. Thus, the warning light will never go away just by driving. You need to get your charging system checked.

The easiest possibility which the otherwise excellent answer by Solar Mike didn't mention is of course a burnt fuse, so be sure to check the fuses before doing more thorough checks. I had on my 1989 Opel Vectra after connecting a current-consuming device to the cigarette lighter socket a burnt fuse which caused the warning light. Solution was to replace the fuse and not to use the current-consuming device anymore.